# C# Regex - starts with pattern1 not contain pattern2

Tags: c#, regex

for the following input string contains all of these:

- a1.aaa[SUBSCRIBED]
- a1.bbb
- a1.ccc
- b1.ddd
- d1.ddd[SUBSCRIBED]

I want to get the output:

- bbb
- ccc

which means: all the words that come after "a1." And not contain the substring "[SUBSCRIBED]"

Comment: I'm sure I saw this question before... What have you tried?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please take a moment to review the tour: https://stackoverflow.com/tour , 
How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve , and more specifically, 
*How to Ask Good Questions* https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask 
- you'll get better feedback and helpful answers if you put some thought in to your problem before coming to SO for help, and by including a specific problem with code *that you've tried* showing effort to solve the problem yourself. You can edit your post once you have an idea of the specific issue.

Comment: @bensagi, Once you come back, please feel free to [check my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45551888/3832970) and if it works, please consider accepting.

Answer (score 0):

> all the words comes after "a1." And not contains the substring
>   "[SUBSCRIBED]"

Why regex? Following is crystal clear:

```
var result = strings
    .Where(s => s.StartsWith("a1.") && !s.Contains("[SUBSCRIBED]"))
    .Select(s => s.Substring(3));
```

Comment: regex will be more efficent, plus i dont know what will be the length of  "a1." (it will be a variable)

Comment: @bensagi1989: regex is not more efficient and it doesnt matter if you use a variable or `"a1."`. Use `s.StartsWith(variable)` and `s.Substring(variable.Length)`

Answer (score 0):

Tim's answer makes sense. However if you insist on it I would venture that a Regex would look like this though.

```
^a1\.(.*)(?<!\[SUBSCRIBED\])$
```

with `^a1` meaning starts with a1
`\.(.*)` taking any number of character
and the negative lookbehind `(?<!\[SUBSCRIBED\])$` would refuse text ending with [SUBSCRIBED]

Comment: Since OP said `a1` will be of variable length, And because they don't seem to accept `b1.ddd` -> `ddd`, regex won't work unless OP adds a MCVE that shows how that `a1` variable is handled.

Comment: I would assume one should inject the variable used in the place of 'a1' when building the regex string. Something like `expressions = $"^{variable}\.(.*)(?<!\[SUBSCRIBED\])$";` On a seperate note, I am unfamiliar with the term MCVE @Mat

Answer (score 0):

You may use

```
^a1\.(?!.*\[SUBSCRIBED])(.*)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/IrmS2x/1).

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `a1\.` - a literal `a1.` substring
- `(?!.*\[SUBSCRIBED])` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is a `[SUBSCRIBED]` substring is present after any 0+ chars (other than newline if the `RegexOptions.Singleline`  option is not used)
- `(.*)` - Group 1: the rest of the line up to the end (if you use `RegexOptions.Singleline`  option, `.` will match newlines as well).

C# code:

```
var result = string.Empty;
var m = Regex.Match(s, @"^a1\.(?!.*\[SUBSCRIBED])(.*)");
if (m.Success) 
{
    result = m.Groups[1].Value;
}
```